# MultiselectComboBox options for be open

Tags: vaadin

How can I achieve this in Vaadin?

```
MultiselectComboBox box = new MultiselectComboBox();
```

I can see a dropdown list which works fine , but I am looking for a function where the dropdown is open by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ListSelect` :-

[ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-listselect.html#components.listselect)